# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Tags: python

Задача - построить график функции `sin(2*3.14*i/50)/cos(2*3.14*i/50)` на Python

```
while i<=50:
    y=math.sin(2*3.14*i/50)/math.cos(2*3.14*i/50)
    if(y>max):
        max=y
    elif(y<min):
        min=y
    i+=1
    print('\n')
    j=1
    while j<=50:
        y= math.ceil(((math.sin(2*3.14*i/50)/math.cos(2*3.14*i/50))-min)*50/(max-min))
        if y==50-j:
            print('*')
        else:
            print (' ')
        j+=1
print(max)
print(min)
```

При запуске выходит ошибка:

> ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero.

Проверял - значения максимума и минимума присваиваются верно, значит беда во внутреннем цикле. Зафэйлил с пробелами, или же в Python так вообще делать нельзя?

**Обновление**

Изначально:

```
import math

min=max=math.sin(2*3.14/50)/math.cos(2*3.14/50)

i=1
```

Значения `max = 15.7029740933...`, `min = -16.53312943...`. Отсчет `i` начинается с 1, изначально `max = min`, а затем присваиваем значения.

Вывел `min` и `max` перед ошибкой. Оба значения *0.126264...* Хотя если убрать внутренний цикл - все нормально. По идее должно 50 раз вывести на экран значения `max` и `min` (15.703... и -16.533).

Comment: значения косинуса math.cos(2*3.14*i/50) может где то  0 попадается ?

Comment: Отсчет `i` начинается с нуля?

Comment: А какие значения используются для инициализации `min` и `max`?

Comment: напечайте `min`, `max` перед ошибкой. Скорее всего на первой итерации `min=max` и поэтому `min-max==0`. Приведите *полный* traceback.

Comment: @Джордан: Вы понимаете что у Вас во внутреннем цикле `/(max-min)` присутствует и поэтому, если `min=max`, то это ведёт к `ZeroDivisionError`? Чтобы функцию нарисовать, используйте [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html)

Comment: @jfs понимаю, но по идее-то внешний цикл должен присваивать другие значения max и min? а в чем беда понять не могу

Comment: если `min=max` хотя бы на *одной* (первой) итерации цикла, то это достаточно чтобы ошибка возникла (что прерывает нормальное исполнение кода). Попробуйте выбросить весь код и оставьте только `min`: `min = 0` `while True: 1/min; min +=1` -- в этом коде `min=0` только на *одной* (первой) итерации цикла, но этого достаточно чтобы ошибка деления на ноль завершила программу (дальнейшие итерации не состоятся, если бы `min=1`, то  это был бы бесконечный цикл с разными значениями `min` на каждой итерации)

Comment: @jfs Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: @jfs Поковырялся с исключениями, но теперь еще одна беда: внутренний цикл не печатает в все результаты в строку, как в C :c

Comment: @Джордан: это отдельный вопрос. Не нужно весь код в вопросе приводить. [Почитайте как Вы можете создать минимальный, но полный пример кода, который может продемонстрировать Вашу новую проблему](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и опубликуйте его как новый вопрос -- не забудьте описать словами, что Вы ожидаете от кода и что конкретно происходит вместо ожидаемого -- если код завершается с ошибкой, то публикуйте ошибку в виде текста *полностью*

Answer (score 2):

Если `min=max` хотя бы на одной (первой) итерации цикла, то это достаточно чтобы ошибка деления на ноль (`ZeroDivisionError`) возникла, что прерывает нормальное исполнение кода.

Чтобы лучше понять что происходит, попробуйте выбросить весь код и оставьте только `min`:

```
min = 0
while True:
    1 / min # выбрасывается ошибка на первой итерации
    min += 1
```

В этом коде `min=0` только на одной (первой) итерации цикла, но этого достаточно чтобы ошибка деления на ноль завершила программу (дальнейшие итерации не состоятся). Eсли `min=1` в начале поставить вместо `min=0`, то это создаст бесконечный цикл с разными значениями `min` на каждой итерации.

Answer (score 1):

Для подобной задачи обычно используют такой подход:

- Первым делом считаются точки по которым строится график (тут же можно посчитать максимум и минимум)
- По точкам строим график

А для циклов в питоне лучше использовать for. Так код легче читается и в таком цикле сложнее сделать ошибку. while в питоне достаточно редкий гость.

Если сложить все вместе, то получится примерно такой код:

```
import math

max_y=min_y=None
ys=[]

for i in range(1,51):
    y=math.sin(2*3.14*i/50)/math.cos(2*3.14*i/50)
    max_y = max(y, max_y) if max_y is not None else y
    min_y = min(y, max_y) if min_y is not None else y
    ys.append(y)

spaces = ' '*50
for y in ys:
    i = math.ceil((max_y - y)*50/(max_y - min_y))
    print(i)
    print(spaces[:i] + '*' + spaces[i+1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Если задача нарисовать звездочками график,
у меня получился такой код:

```
import math

min=max=math.sin(2*3.14/50)/math.cos(2*3.14/50)
i=1

while i<=50:
    y=math.sin(2*3.14*i/50)/math.cos(2*3.14*i/50)
    if(y>max):
        max=y
    elif(y<min):
        min=y
    i+=1
print(max)
print(min)

j=1
while j<=50:
    y= math.ceil(((math.sin(2*3.14*j/50)/math.cos(2*3.14*j/50))-min)*50/(max-min))

    for pr in range(int(y)):
        print (" ",end='');
    print ("*")
    j+=1
```